# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare calculateAge() previously declared

Tags: php

I am trying to calculate the age but I am getting this error

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare calculateAge() (previously declared

---

```
    $age = $row3['DBirth'];

    function calculateAge($date)
   {
    list($year,$month,$day) = explode("-",$date);

    $year_diff  = date("Y") - $year;

    $month_diff = date("m") - $month;

    $day_diff   = date("d") - $day;

    if ($day_diff < 0 || $month_diff < 0) $year_diff--;

      return $year_diff;

  }

  echo 'Student age is'.calculateAge($age).' years old';
```

Any idea ?
Thanks,

Comment: its calculating perfectly but if you have included some other file which also has same function then you must remove it and then check again

Comment: Or wrap the definition around `if( function_exists('calculateAge') == FALSE ) {}`

Comment: Usually a result of include'ing the same file twice. Changing any include() to include_once() in your code should fix it :) include_once() should be used for any classes or procedural code you use, saving include() for simple HTML forms or menu's etc.

Answer (score -1):

The function already exists, you have two `function calculateAge(...`s in your code.

The "previously declared" in your error message will tell you where the first one is declared, and the very end of the error message will tell you where the second is.